# Сложный SQL запрос. Выборка значения из одного поля одной таблицы по разным параметрам и их вывод в разные столбцы

Tags: sql, sql-server

Всем привет! Замучился с написанием одного select SQL запроса на MS SQL 2012. Вот в чем задача: 
Есть иерархическая таблица подразделений podr в которой каждое отделение в составе отдела, 
а каждый отдел в составе управления:

```
Id |  Name             | Upravlenie | Otdel | Otdelenie | Level
1  |  Управление1      |    122     |  270  |    382    |   1
2  |  У1-Отдел1        |    122     |  271  |    383    |   2
3  |  У1-О1-Отделение1 |    122     |  271  |    384    |   3
4  |  У1-О1-Отделение2 |    122     |  271  |    385    |   3
5  |  У1-О1-Отделение3 |    122     |  271  |    386    |   3
6  |  У1-Отдел2        |    122     |  272  |    387    |   2
7  |  У1-О2-Отделение1 |    122     |  272  |    388    |   3
8  |  У1-О2-Отделение2 |    122     |  272  |    389    |   3
9  |  У1-О2-Отделение3 |    122     |  272  |    390    |   3
10 |  Управление2      |    123     |  273  |    391    |   1
11 |  У2-Отдел1        |    122     |  274  |    392    |   2
12 |  У2-О1-Отделение1 |    122     |  274  |    393    |   3
13 |  У2-О1-Отделение2 |    122     |  274  |    394    |   3
14 |  У2-О1-Отделение3 |    122     |  274  |    395    |   3
```

Есть таблица работников dolzh:

```
Id | Surname      | Name   | Otdelenie
1  | Pupkin       | Vasya  | 385
2  | Petrov       | Petya  | 394
```

Нужно сделать выборку из двух таблиц и вывести в итоге такую:

Id | Surname      | Name   | Otdelenie_name   | Otdel_name | Upravlenie_name |

```
1  | Pupkin       | Vasya  | У1-О1-Отделение2 | У1-Отдел1  | Управление1     |
2  | Petrov       | Petya  | У2-О1-Отделение2 | У2-Отдел1  | Управление2     |
```

т.е. на каждого работника из таблицы dolzh по коду Отделения в select-выборку нужно добавить три столбца расшифрованных значений Отделения, Отдела, Управления.
Никак не получается написать такой запрос, максимум что получается, это

```
Id | Surname      | Name   | Otdelenie_name   |
1  | Pupkin       | Vasya  | У1-О1-Отделение2 |
2  | Petrov       | Petya  | У2-О1-Отделение2 |
```

А самое хитрое, - имя отдела и имя управления вывести тут не могу. т.е. нужно поле Name из таблицы podr вывести трижды в новой таблицы по разным параметрам. Понимаю, что тут нужно джойнить, но как это делать в одной таблице по одному и тому же полю, разобраться не получается!

Comment: Не понятно, как по таблице подразделений, зная id отделения из пользователя, например 385 добраться до отдела и управления. Иерархические таблицы строятся совершенно не так.

Comment: А так то джоините таблицу 3 раза, разумеется с разными алиасами

Comment: Зная уникальный код отделения 385, из таблицы podr мы по этому коду определяем Name подразделения. Далее смотрим в этой  найденной строке коды отдела (271) и управления (122). Далее по этим кодам определяем в таблице podr, что для кода управления 122,где поле level = 1 расшифрованное имя управления будет Name из этой строки т.е.  "Управление1". Понятен принцип?  Также и для Отдела с level = 2. Как это написать в SQL запросе, у меня нет идей...

Comment: Mike , если понимаете как это трижды джойнить, напишите пожалуйста кодом к алиасам Otdelenie_name, Otdel_name, Upravlenie_name. У меня вообще никак, я пока плохо понимаю возможности JOIN ;(

Comment: Ответ вам в общем то написали. Но структуру надо пересматривать ... У вас нарушена 2я нормальная форма. В БД потенциально могут быть ошибки, например управление окажется не такое в записи отдела, нежели в записи отделения. Правильная структура должна содержать всего 3 поля: ID, название, ID-родителя. У управления скажем ID1 у отдела в нем ID=2 и parent_ID=1, у отделения в отделе ID=3, parent_ID=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно есть способ покрасивее извернуться, но как-то так:

```
SELECT a.surname, a.name, b1.Name, b2.Name, b3.Name FROM dolzh AS a
    LEFT JOIN podr AS b1 ON (a.Otdelenie = b1.Otdelenie) 
    LEFT JOIN podr AS b2 ON (b1.Otdel = b2.Otdel           AND b2.Level = 2 )
    LEFT JOIN podr AS b3 ON (b1.Upravlenue = b3.Upravlenue AND b3.Level = 1 )
```

P.S. `Petrov` по вашим данным не во втором управлении, а иерархию обычно создают так, и по глубине определяется, что чем является( отдел - не отдел ):

```
Id |  Name             | Parent_id
----------------------------------
1  |  Управление1      |    null
2  |  У1-Отдел1        |    1
3  |  У1-О1-Отделение1 |    2
4  |  У1-О1-Отделение2 |    2
5  |  У1-О1-Отделение3 |    2
6  |  У1-Отдел2        |    1
7  |  У1-О2-Отделение1 |    6
8  |  У1-О2-Отделение2 |    6
9  |  У1-О2-Отделение3 |    6
10 |  Управление2      |    null
11 |  У2-Отдел1        |    10
12 |  У2-О1-Отделение1 |    11
13 |  У2-О1-Отделение2 |    11
14 |  У2-О1-Отделение3 |    11
```

```
Id | Surname      | Name   | Otdelenie_id
-----------------------------------------
1  | Pupkin       | Vasya  |   4
2  | Petrov       | Petya  |  13
```

Comment: Да, id с 11 по 14 Upravlenie = 123. Заметили :) Ваш код прекрасно работает, большое спасибо! Удивительно быстро, сам день бился на этим, спросил на форуме и моментальный ответ. Вот что сказать, у профессионала пару минут уходит на такой запрос, а новичек и за день бывает не может составить. Респект! Над структурой конечно надо подумать будет...